# How to download an off-line installation for Microsoft Visual Basic 2017 with IDE only?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation, ide, offline

I want to download an off-line installation for Microsoft Visual Basic 2017 for Windows Desktop with the IDE only. I do not need any of "Azure", "Android", "Cordova", "Xamarin", "PythonTools.Django" or "Apple.Sdk".

I followed instructions on this page :[Create a network installation of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio)

I downloaded the **vs_community.exe** file.

Then I ran the command:

**vs_community.exe --layout c:\vs2017offline --lang en-US**

The program launched **setup.exe**, which has already downloaded more than 23 GB (**23 Gigabytes!**) of data to the off-line folder, most of which I have no intention of ever using. And it keeps downloading without any indication as to when it is going to complete. So much data is very difficult to store, especially that I do not need most of it.

**How can I download only the Visual Basic part with the IDE?**

Comment: I stopped the downloading after it has downloaded 25 GB. Apparently, it was going to download even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you used is to download the whole VS 2017 offline packages with English version, so it is a huge one, if you just want to use the VB.NET, you need to customize the network layout that described in your shared document. Using the command-line parameter **“--add**” to specify [workload or component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community). If --add is used, only those workloads and components specified with --add will be downloaded. If --add is not used, all workload and components will be downloaded.

Refer to your description, I tried open cmd and type the command: **vs_Community.exe --layout C:\vs2017offline --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --lang en-US** to download the partly offline installer and the total size as below:
[image]

During the installation, I only checked the workload ‘.NET desktop development’ and since the workload ‘Visual Studio core editor’ is included with VS community 2017 to install. After the successful installation, I open VS community 2017 to create new project, the VB templates like the following. If you want to more VB templates like ASP.NET or Windows Universal, you can use the parameter “--add” to specific more the corresponding workload like *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal* and others, it depends on your development requirement.
[image]